# How to add an image as ground plane in Citadel

Tags: gazebo-citadel, ignition-citadel

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So, I tried to follow several like this [link](https://ignitionrobotics.org/api/gazebo/4.1/meshtofuel.html)
And [this](https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/citadel/sdf_worlds)

Then I tried to follow [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=color_model), but I'm convinced that this is for classic gazebo only, not Citadel.

I still can't find why it couldn't load the image.

Here is the current plane:

[image: image description]

The goal is to have this
[image: image description]

I downloaded directly from this [link](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/selbystorage/wp-content/uploads/2017/July/conde_world.zip)

The directories is like this;
[image: image description]

So the sdf with worlds is this:

```
      <model name='conde_world'>
  <static>true</static>
  <link name='link_ground'>
    <visual name='visual_ground'>
      <geometry>
        <plane>
          <normal>0 0 1</normal>
          <size>174 417</size>
        </plane>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <script>
          <uri>model://conde_world/materials/scripts</uri>
          <uri>model://conde_world/materials/textures</uri>
          <name>Floor/Image</name>
        </script>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <plane>
          <normal>0 0 1</normal>
          <size>174 417</size>
        </plane>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
</model>
```

The question is why can't I load it? Is it a bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27379/how-to-add-an-image-as-ground-plane-in-citadel/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2021-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thanks to @chapulina for give me a new route to explore,

I finally manage to find a way to import an image. Here is the snippet of how you import.

```
  <material>
    <ambient>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</ambient>
    <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
    <specular>1 0.8 0.8 1</specular>
    <pbr>
        <metal>
          <albedo_map>floor.png</albedo_map>
          <normal_map>floor.png</normal_map>
        </metal>
      </pbr>
  </material>
```

Keep that in mind, this will find where the model.sdf is in. Just add your picture to there.

Also `<Specular>` is a [bug](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/issues/1038) atm.

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2021-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Take a look at the tutorial [Migrating SDF files from Gazebo classic to Ignition](https://ignitionrobotics.org/api/gazebo/5.1/migrationsdf.html).

Material scripts aren't supported on Ignition, so you'll nee to use the `<pbr>` tag.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2021-09-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2021-09-17**:
Thank you! I'm very honored to have your reply!

Anyway,

Related to `<pbr>`

I followed similar to the link which results as this

```
        <pbr>
            <metal>
                <albedo_map>floor.png</albedo_map>
            </metal>
        </pbr>
```

which results as this
[image: image description]

So I removed `<metal>` and it is same. So I reverted

I'm looking to import an image only without OBJ MTL COLLAD

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2021-09-17**:
Characters limit reached.

Anyway is there any docs or tutorial more details about ? I'm interested to learn more about it or even